# $-f^{(5)}+2f^{(3)}-f'=0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation $$-f^{(5)}+2f^{(3)}-f'=0$$

**My idea**

The equation resembles the polynomial $-x^5+2x^3-x$ which can be written as $(x^2+x)(x-1)(-x^2+1)$. Now taking $«x^2=f''(x)»,\ldots $, we have to solve
$(f''+f')(f'-f)(-f''+f)=0$.
As we know (from Lagrange's theorem) the solutions of each of these three equations, this leads to the system$$\left [\begin{matrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\end{matrix}\right |\left .\begin{matrix}c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x\\c_3e^x\\c_4e^x+c_5e^{-x}\end{matrix}\right ].$$And how to solve the system is reasonably simple, but I don't see the solution presented by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: "without resorting to the theory of differential equations and general theorems" seems **incredibly restrictive**. How would you even know what a differential equation is without resorting to the theory of differential equations? Definitions are at the core of any mathematical theory. Whoever authored your question does not seem to know how to phrase proper limitations.

Comment: What do you mean by "without resorting to the theory of differential equations"? Your approach is essentially the ansatz $f(x) = e^{tx}$ which is arguably well within the theory of ODEs.

Comment: Your idea of trying to "factor" the differential equation is interesting, and some equations can be solved in this manner.  However, you cannot factor a differential operator the same way as a polynomial.  Typical method for solve equation like yours is to let $x = e^{rt}$, substitute, and solve for $r$.  This is known as the characteristic equation.

Comment: Your factorization can be further broken down to $-x(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$. One way to use this is to note that if $L_1,L_2,L_3$ denote the linear operators
$$
L_1(f) = f', \quad L_2(f) = (f' + f), \quad L_3(f) = f' - f,
$$
then the question is asking for the kernel of $L_1 \circ L_2^2 \circ L_3^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Method 1:  Characteristic eqn.*
$$x = e^{rt}.$$
$$-r^5e^{rt}+2r^3e^{rt}-re^{rt} = 0.$$
$$(-r^5+2r^3-r) = 0.$$
$$r(r^4-2r^2+1) = 0\implies r(r^2-1)(r^2-1) = 0.$$
$$r = 0,\quad r = -1\text{ (double root)},\quad r = 1\text{ (double root)}.$$
General solution is therefore: $$x(t) = c_0+(c_1+c_2t)e^t+(c_3+c_4t)e^{-t}.$$

*Method 2:  Factoring:*
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)f = 0.$$
Integrate once to get
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)f = c_0.$$
Let $g(t) = f''-f$. Then,
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)g = c_0.$$
$$g(t) = -c_0+c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}.$$
Then,
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-1\right)f = -c_0+c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}.$$
Solve this using method of characteristics, and you find same solution as before.

This is a good question, because it shows us that factoring differential operators cannot be viewed in exactly the same way as factoring polynomials.  As the OP demonstrates, we can also factor the operator as
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+\frac{d}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{d}{dt}-1\right)\left(-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+1\right)f = 0.$$

Unlike for polynomials, we **cannot** set each factor equal to zero to obtain the correct solution.  From the third factor, we would get as a part of the solution basis sines and cosines, which is not what we obtained above.